# 3/4 Inch CPVC Pipe Run Underground - Low Pressure

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, cpvc

I tied into a water line that was capped off in my crawlspace.  It is a CPVC water line that used to run to a sink in a utility room of my home.  Water pressure when the line was connected was just as the rest of the home.  I have now tied into this line and run CPVC pipe underground for about 25 feet and connected to a spigot.  Water pressure from the spigot at best is a slow drip.  I have checked all joints/connectors of the CPVC pipe and there are no leaks.

What do I need to do or check in order to get adequate water pressure?

**EDIT**
And for clarification the CPVC pipe runs about 1 foot down to the ground, then runs about 18 inches up to the spigot, the rest of the run is flat.

Comment: Is it *only* the new line and spigot that has the low pressure issue? Assuming **yes**, I would turn off the supply and remove the spigot, then test by having someone open it up whilst standing at the open line with a bucket...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - yes, it is only the new line that has the low pressure.  I'll see if I can get someone over to assist with your recommendation this afternoon.  :)

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - with the spigot removed, water pressure is still low at the end.